# Android 11 no longer able to get album by id

Tags: android, media, android-contentresolver, android-11

My music application no longer works in Android 11. I am not able to get albums by id from content resolver. The code bellow works on Android 10 and not on 11

```
public final static String ALBUM_ID = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;

public Observable<Cursor> getAlbumById(int albumId) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        final String where = ALBUM_TITLE + " != '' AND " + ALBUM_ID + "=?";
        final String[] columns = {ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_FIRST_YEAR, ALBUM_LAST_YEAR, ALBUM_NUMBER_OF_SONGS, ALBUM_ARTIST_ID, ARTIST_NAME};
        final String sort = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
        final String[] values = { String.valueOf(albumId) };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = MediaStore.this.contentResolver.query(ALBUM_URI, columns, where, values, sort);
            if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                throw new MediaItemNotFoundException();
            }
            emitter.onNext(cursor);
            emitter.onComplete();
        } catch (MediaItemNotFoundException e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(new MediaStoreQueryException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause()));
        }
    });
}
```

Permissions I am using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".AndroidApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

When I query the content resolver asking for that album id I get an empty cursor (0 items, can't make move next, it returns false). (This code works perfectly on Android 10 and below) On the other hand, by using this clause:

```
final String where = ALBUM_TITLE + " != '';
```

I get all albums in device.

When do so and get the int value in the ALBUM_ID of the album I get the exact same value I am looking for. However, if I request the string value I get another completely different value. Curiously, if I query the content resolver using that string value as album id I do get the desired album. Somehow the resolver is only looking at the String field of the column.

PD: On Android 10, string and int fields of that column have the same value. Different values on Android 11.

Any idea what might occur? Maybe permissions? I have read Android 11 docs and changes but found nothing related to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I have found the solution if any comes into the same issue (I hope not, it's pretty silly) The thing is that in Android 11 ids are no longer that small (like 1, 2, 12, 34, etc). The id value was kind long and it couldn't be retrieved as int. Actually when you wanted to get the int value you just got the las 8 or 9 values of the long field. Conclusions: You must always save ids as String or Long values.